# Unable to match thead and tbody width in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

When I am passing width to ng2-smart-table columns in ts file then thead and tbody not matching.

If I remove below css from ng2-smart-table.component.scss file then width is matching but tbody vertical scroll goes off

```
 tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

thead,
tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

can anybody help me on this....